# color regions on nvd3 line with focus chart directive

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 line with focus chart angular directive for my dashboard. Is there any method for shading the regions based on the x axis values. That is i want regions parallel to y axis to be coloured based on the x axis values. Any help and any ideas in this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you update the question with some code you have done so far?